# Extension for view controller using Bool in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, boolean, extension-methods, viewcontroller

I'm try to make an extension for a view controller. It is a simple view with tap recognizer. If it is pushed once, the background color should change from magenta to  orange. By the next push it should be magenta again.

If I do it for the concrete VC, let say, StartVC, it works. Here is the code:

```
import UIKit

class StartVC: UIViewController {
    // bool
    var colorChanged = false

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.magenta
        setMyTouchableView2()
    }
}

extension StartVC {
    // make touchable view
    func setMyTouchableView2() {
        let myView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 50, height: 50))
        myView.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow

        // add gesture recognizer
        let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(changeColor2(_:)))
        myView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)
        myView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

        view.addSubview(myView)
    }

    func changeColor2(_ recognizer:UITapGestureRecognizer){
        if(colorChanged) {
            view.backgroundColor = UIColor.magenta
        } else {
            view.backgroundColor = UIColor.orange
        }

        colorChanged = !colorChanged
    }
}
```

But if I try to generalize this extension for any view controller, I get the following problem: I cant put my boolean (colorChanged) inside the view controller because the extension will not see it. How can I solve it?

Here is the code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    // bool
    var colorChanged = false

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.magenta
        setMyTouchableView()
    }
}

extension UIViewController {
    // make touchable view
    func setMyTouchableView() {
        let myView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 50, height: 50))
        myView.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow

        // add gesture recognizer
        let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(changeColor(_:)))
        myView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)
        myView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

        view.addSubview(myView)
    }

    func changeColor(_ recognizer:UITapGestureRecognizer){
        if(colorChanged) {
            view.backgroundColor = UIColor.magenta
        } else {
            view.backgroundColor = UIColor.orange
        }
    }
```

Comment: How about passing your "colorChanged" variable as an argument in changeColor() ?

Comment: Also you could just change the test condition to "if view.backgroundColor == UIColor.magenta" change to orange and vice versa

Comment: Classes can of course override a superclass’s method, but with extensions you can’t. Methods or properties in an extension cannot have the same name as methods or properties in the original class.

Comment: I tried it: it will be never executed.

Comment: To Sneha: I tried both. It will be never executed and the color will not changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use struct to make a global variable -

```
   struct GlobalStruct {
    static var colorChanged = false
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.magenta
        setMyTouchableView()
    }
}

extension UIViewController {
    // make touchable view
    func setMyTouchableView() {
        let myView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 50, height: 50))
        myView.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow

        // add gesture recognizer
        let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(changeColor(_:)))
        myView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)
        myView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

        view.addSubview(myView)
    }

    func changeColor(_ recognizer:UITapGestureRecognizer){
        if(GlobalStruct.colorChanged) {
            view.backgroundColor = UIColor.magenta
        } else {
            view.backgroundColor = UIColor.orange
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Good idea. But I tried it now: it work only once. You cannot repeat it, as far as I can see.

Comment: You have to change color as you required with `GlobalStruct.colorChanged = true` like that.

Comment: Yes! I have to add: GlobalStruct.colorChanged = !GlobalStruct.colorChanged. Now it works. Thank you so much for help!

Answer (score 2):

Extensions cannot have stored property by default. But, if you really need this you can create it via objc runtime

```
private var associationKey: UInt8 = 111 // Some constant

extension ViewController {
    var colorChanged: Bool {
        get {
            return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &associationKey) as! Bool
        }
        set {
            objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &associationKey, newValue, .OBJC_ASSOCIATION_ASSIGN)
        }
    }
}
```

But you can have a problem, that several controllers would change this flag. So you can also try to use protocols

```
protocol ColorChangable {
    var colorChange: Bool { get set }
}

extension ColorChangable where Self: UIViewController {
    func setMyTouchableView {
        // Your logic
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var colorChange: Bool

    func viewDidLoad() {
        self.viewDidLoad()

        setMyTouchableView()
    }
}

extension ViewController: ColorChangable {}
```